# Callkit: Call log recent is not showing outgoing call for video call

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am implementing callKit in swift, for video outgoing call recent log is not showing history from my app. For Audio calls, log is showing history from my app.

For video calls I am setting `isVideo = true` of `CXStartCallAction` property.

```
let handle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: handle)

startCallAction.isVideo = true//if setting false recent log showing history for true no recent history is coming

let transaction = CXTransaction()
transaction.addAction(startCallAction)

requestTransaction(transaction, action: "startCall")
```

Recent log is supposed to display the history as a video call but it is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you have not configured the `CXProvider` to support video.

```
let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "MyApp")
providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
...
let provider = CXProvider(configuration: providerConfiguration)
```